# How to check whether the user input is matched with the record in text file in linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have a text file called `student.txt` and there are some records in the text file.
The format of the records are `StudentID|Name|ContactNumber|EmailAddress` and the records are as follows:

```
21PMR07222|Steven|011-1234567|steven@yahoo.com
21PMR07123|John|012-3456789|john@yahoo.com
21PMR07221|Amy|017-4567890|amy@gmail.com
```

The user will need to enter the student ID to search the details. May I know how to check whether the student ID entered by the user is matched with the student ID in the text file and display the details of the student ID entered by the user?

Code for searching with student ID:

```
echo -n "Enter Student ID to search (eg: 21PMR12345): "
read studentID
```

The details of the student should be displayed as below:

```
Student ID: 21PMR07222
Name: Steven
Contact Number: 011-1234567
Email Address: steven.thoo@yahoo.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly direct option is to use `awk`:

```sh
echo -n "Enter Student ID to search (eg: 21PMR12345): "
read studentID
awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '$1 == id { printf "Student ID: %s\nName: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' < student.txt
```

This will print any matching line (or lines) based on the input from the user matching exactly the StudentID from column 1 of student.txt. Here I'm asking awk to split each line of input based on the pipe symbol (`|`) and also passing it the input from the user as awk variable "id". If column/field 1 (`$1`) exactly matches the value of that variable, then we print the matching line with the required format.